Postgresql Data Migration Tips
I would like to ask for your suggestions on how to proceed with a data migration involving a PostgreSQL database.
It’s an academic system with many tables, and I need to separate the data of two universities.
I plan to develop scripts so I can send them to University A, which will return the data from University B for me to import into my PostgreSQL database.
Could you suggest how I should approach this process? What tools should I use?
I appreciate any help you can offer.

Consider posting this question to DBA Stack Exchange. As presented, the question is not about a programming problem and is therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow.
